# Making use of CSS vs Sass (SCSS) - base class issues and redundency

Tags: css, sass, oocss, precompiler

I'm trying to clean up my CSS to be cleaner by using SCSS.

Standard CSS:

```
.dark-hr,
.light-hr { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
.dark-hr {
  background-color: #595959;
}
.light-hr {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

vs SCSS:

```
.generic-hr { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
.dark-hr {
  @extend .generic-hr;
  background-color: #595959;
}
.light-hr {
  @extend .generic-hr;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Is there any way to avoid creating the 'generic-hr' class that won't be used? I was hoping that some kind of nest would work well.
In this scenario the CSS is definitely way cleaner and more readable than SCSS.

Ideally I would need this to work in SCSS:

```
.## {
  // base class that is not outputted
  .dark-hr {
    //attributes the extend the base class '.##'
  }
  .light-hr {
    //attributes the extend the base class '.##'
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 .dark-hr, .light-hr {
   //shared attributes defined by '.##'
 }
 .dark-hr {
   // overrides
 }
 .light-hr {
   // overrides
 }
```

Comment: you could use `[class*='-hr']` , which basically means any class that has `-hr` in it, at least then you won't need to `@extend` everytime and if you chose to add more `.-hr` classes, you won't need to edit/extend anything

Comment: @ashley You *could* do it that way, but what happens if you need to add a class that doesn't have the "-hr" suffix, but extends `.light-hr`?  You have to remember to extend `[class*='-hr']` as well, which is easily forgotten if the project has been set aside for a few months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're wanting to use is an *extend class* (I call them "silent classes"), which is signified by using a `%` instead of a `.`.

```
hr%base { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
.dark-hr {
  @extend hr%base;
  background-color: #595959;
}
.light-hr {
  @extend hr%base;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you normally do something like this:

```
.generic-hr { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  &.dark {
    background-color: #595959;
  }
  &.light {
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }
}
```

Comment: That would include `.generic-hr` in the output. See @cimmanon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

My pattern for this kind of thing is a mixin:

```
@mixin generic-hr { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
.dark-hr {
  @include generic-hr;
  background-color: #595959;
}
.light-hr {
  @include generic-hr;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

This has the added advantage of being extensible, so if you find yourself needing several selectors with really similar properties you can add in variables:

```
@mixin generic-hr($background-color: transparent) { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 15px 0px; 
  background-color: $background-color;
}
.dark-hr {
  @include generic-hr(#595959);
}
.light-hr {
  @include generic-hr(#cccccc);
}
.medium-hr {
  @include generic-hr(#818181);
}
```

Comment: Also a good solution. I prefer the extend answer though because A) mixins are usually in their own files and B) is closer to my original required solution. Your solution **could** however mean less code. Wish I could mark 2 answers as correct. :(